# How do I convert this table layout to a div layout?

Tags: html, css

I was recommended by a friend to use the div layout, but I cant get it to work.

I am trying to accomplish the following diagram:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|           Fixed Height = 50             |
+-----------------------------------------+
|         |                  |            |
|         |                  |            |
|  Fixed  |     Whatever     |    Fixed   |
|  Width  |     Remains      |    Width   | Total Height = 500px
|    =    |      In All      |      =     | Total Width  = 600px
|   150   |    Directions    |     150    |
|         |                  |            |
|         |                  |            |
|         |                  |            |                    
+-----------------------------------------+
|           Fixed Height = 50             |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Essentially, convert 
http://jsfiddle.net/qPgVx/ .
to
http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/juckh/7/ (but with divs)

The reason that this isnt arbitrary, is because the entire form can be dynamically resized with js and I want the center to expand and contract as necessary.

My problem is that I cannot get the middle to fill the height. How do I fix this?

Comment: So, all dimensions are fixed? Even the middle appears to be (`300px` wide and `400px` high).

Comment: Also, which browsers do you need to support? IE7?

Comment: The catch is that the entire thing is dynamically resized with js. Hence, I cannot simple plug in widths. Ideally im trying to support IE6, but if not, then oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/kBHCR/

As you can see, when the `width` and `height` of `.Window` are adjusted, everything resizes.

This will work in IE7+ and all modern browsers.

It blatantly won't work in IE6. If you need to support IE6, you can either use JavaScript for only IE6, or you can stick with a `<table>`. If you want to support IE6, there's a price to pay.

**CSS:**

```
.Window {
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
    position: relative;
}
.Window-Top {
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgb(128,128,128); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(167,167,167) 25%, rgb(208,208,208) 78%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(167,167,167) 25%, rgb(208,208,208) 78%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(167,167,167) 25%, rgb(208,208,208) 78%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(167,167,167) 25%, rgb(208,208,208) 78%);
}
.Window-Bottom {
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,128,128);
}
.Window-Content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.Window-Content-Left {
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
.Window-Content-Right {
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}
.Window-Content-Content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 150px;
    right: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(0,255,0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I was recommended by a friend to use the div layout,

First of all: "Tables are evil" is a myth. If a table works for you, there is no reason to change the layout.

> but I cant get it to work.

No surprise here :-) There are various ways to simulate a table with `div`s but it's not trivial. Maybe the same people who say "don't use tables" should have come up with more simple and reliable ways to replace tables with CSS. CSS can do a lot but it's very hard to create several elements with the same height in CSS without using JavaScript.

If you still want to try (and I suggest to do so you can learn about limitations of CSS), search the web for "css mullti column layout".

Here is a good article to start: [Multi-Column Layouts Climb Out of the Box](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlayouts/)

Comment: "Tables are evil" _is_ a myth. "Tables for _layout_ are evil" is absolutely true.

Comment: There's been simple CSS to reliably simulate tables with `div`s since [1998](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/), it's just the the world's richest software company didn't get around to implementing it until [2009](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8).

Comment: @MrMisterMan: This is only true if you can afford to put countless hours into fixing your layout for all browsers, all display sizes and all values of content.height.

Comment: Just to give an example: Using a `table`, the layout works for any size. The accepted solution only works for a fixed size layout.

Comment: HTML is supposed to describe data. The content of a website isn't tabular data, it makes no sense to put your entire website in a table. There are thousands upon thousands of websites coded without table layouts and they work just fine. It's a shame there are people  who think doing it properly isn't worth the effort.

Comment: @MrMisterMan: What you want is of no importance to the many different browsers out there. The bugs and limitations don't give a damn what the standard says. You might fake a table using other approaches but in the end, you're just wasting your time. That doesn't mean I'm using tables for everything (which is bad) but I'm not going to surrender a useful tool to some religious belief.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display:table` property for this

Check this example

### http://jsfiddle.net/qPgVx/17/

**OR**

If you have fixed height then write like this:

### http://jsfiddle.net/qPgVx/20/

Comment: why doesnt everyone use this, whats the catch?

Answer (score 0):

Use floating divs for the middle 3 divs.

```
.Window-Content-Left {   
  ... 
  float:left;
  ...
}

.Window-Content-Right {   
  ... 
  float:right;
  ...
}
```

Don't forget to clear the floats if needed:

```
clear: both;
```

Comment: Note: This only works if the three columns have the same background.

Comment: @chacham15 You didn't clear the floats. Also you need to add some content to the two side div's and give the main content a width http://jsfiddle.net/DV3tn/2/

Comment: Thats the catch, I dont want to specify a width for the center.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.pixy.cz/blogg/clanky/css-3col-layout/) or [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/).
Basically, they use margins on the middle `<div>` and then position the sidebars in the margins, with special care for the same-height look.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qPgVx/19/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all dimensions are fixed you can do something like that:

http://jsfiddle.net/qPgVx/9/

You basically need to float all three middle divs and use another div that uses clear:both. More on that you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788885/why-this-clear-both-doesnt-prevent-wrapping)

**EDIT**: Ok, so you need a liquid layout. The best solution I've found for that is the following example:

http://www.alistapart.com/d/negativemargins/ex5.htm

from this article:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/negativemargins/

The problem with the middle column not expanding to 100% of the height is common and the technique I use to solve it is called "faux columns". Basically you use a background image or a wrapper div that imitates the background color of your middle column. The article above covers that two.

More on faux columns:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Comment: Updated the question to explain further.